# How do I get Sane to change its 'Printerdefinition' in 'Copy' mode?

Tags: printing, scanner

Ubuntu 14.04 - Xsane 0.998 - Samsung SCX-4100 Printer/Scanner

After many months of effort & lots of much appreciated help [recorded on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread....333579&page=2] the SCX-4100 will scan.

I now want to do a photocopy.

I've looked for Help and similar Qs here but not found the answer to this very simple Q:

How do I get Sane to change its 'Printerdefinition' in 'Copy' mode? The problem is thus:

I want a photocopy of a document. I open 'Xsane Image Scanning Program' > change top rt hand box to 'Copy' > no result > inspect box displaying 'New Printer' > this cannot be changed despite a message saying 'Select Printerdefinition Shift-F1/F2/....>' which produces no result

thanks 
Nic

Answer (score 0):

I went up to help on the Menu line;

read the COPY section of the help menu; so you need to go to **Preferences**;

then **COPY**;

then you need to set up the printer; I had never done that;

eg our printer is MG3100USB so I entered that in the new printer option;
set it up to copy; it all seems to work on our system

Comment: Many thanks for that. Although Sane is a wonderful piece of work its instructions are far from intuitive for a layperson. At first I couldn't find the instructions to go to PREFERENCES until I found it in the section called ZOOM FACTOR[?!]. Looking at 'Preferences'>Copy I now need to learn an awful lot of printer jargon - eg I type SCX-4100 into 'NAME' but that doesn't change the 'PRINTER SELECTION' box. Also I have no idea what 'COMMAND', 'ICM PROFILE'. Is there a SANE User guide? {Why can't I say any more? I would really like to know how to use 'RETURN, BOLD, UNDERLINE etc in these posts}

Comment: Preferences is on the Menu list of our xsane; I have entered our MG as a printer; I see to add any more I now go to the bottom of the COPY section to "add a new printer"; HELP; or a sane guide; is at the right of the menu; the F1 key activates it; with xsane open, just hit the F1 key!! ICM profile has to do with colour http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqendbranchprintable.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl4000cn_all&faqid=faq00002364_000&printable=true you will find google helps you with many doubts